# How to go from Texture2DContent to Texture2D in a content processor?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-content-pipeline, metaprogramming

I'm using reflection to create a manifest of all assets, strongly typed.

It's working fine for my own types: I get the type of the asset, if a processor is ran on it I get the output type. Then I check to see if there's a `ContentSerializerRuntimeTypeAttribute` applied to the type. If so, then I get the `RuntimeType` value and do a `Type.GetType()` to get the type back.

The problem I have is if the type is `Texture2DContent` (for example) as that doesn't have the `ContentSerializerRuntimeTypeAttribute`.

**How can I go from a `Type` representing `Texture2DContent` to a `Type` representing `Texture2D`?**

I know I can just check for `EndsWith("Content")` as a last resort, but how to I get the namespace qualified type so I can get my `Type` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all Types that inherit from `ContentTypeWriter` and have generic argument of `Texture2DContent` (actualy i think writer exists only for TextureContent), create instance of them and then call `GetRuntimeType`

Comment: Instead of getting only `ContentTypeWriter<T>` for my `T` i got all writers that had the `ContentTypeWriterAttribute` and were inherited from `ContentTypeWriter`. I then instanciated them all and picked the one that had the correct `.TargetType`.